# Updating loaded DataTable with Ajax is losing CSS styles and jQuery events in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a DataTable builded with Bootstrap CSS:

```
<table id="as-index-view-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered display-none dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">
                Potencial Cliente / Cliente
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssignmentState.Name)
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateDue)
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-3">
                Atribuída a
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="@Url.Action(MVC.Assignment.Details(item.Id))">
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lead.Name)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client.Name)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <span style="color: #cfcfcf">@(item.Client == null ? "P" : "C")</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignmentState.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateDue)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Loaded via Javascript:

```
var _asIndexViewTable = $("#as-index-view-table");
var _asIndexViewFilter = $("#as-index-view-filter");

// initialize the table that lists the Leads in the Index View
var _indexViewTable_Init = function () {

    _asIndexViewTable
        // only show the table when it's loaded
        .on('init.dt', function () {
            _asIndexViewTable.show();
        })
        .DataTable({
            // set the element's position
            "dom": '<"top"i>rft<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
            // set the language of the table based on the culture
            "language": {
                "url": "/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.pt.lang.txt"
            },
            //save the state of the table (ordered by column)
            stateSave: true
        });
};
```

Based on a filter (integrated with jquery-octofilter - http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Tags-Input-Plugin-with-Categorized-Suggestions-Octofilter/) I refresh the data from the table using Ajax:

```
var _indexViewRefreshDataTable = function (statesList) {

    // hide the refreshing process
    _asIndexViewTable.hide();

    var arrayDatos = {
        'assigmentStatesList': statesList
    };

    //_asIndexViewTable.fnClearTable();

    _asIndexViewTable
        // only show the table when it's loaded
        .on('init.dt', function () {
            _asIndexViewTable.show();
        })
        .DataTable({
        // set the element's position
        "dom": '<"top"i>rft<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        // set the language of the table based on the culture
        "language": {
            "url": "/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.pt.lang.txt"
        },
        //save the state of the table (ordered by column)
        stateSave: true,
        destroy: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Assignment/List",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc" : '',
            "data": arrayDatos
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "State", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Subject", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "DateDue", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
    });
};
```

The problem is that after refreshing the table, I lose all the CSS and the data values for jQuery events.